# Wordpress - Retrieving specific posts from the current user

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post with 2 fields, the first field being the user, and the second one being a table, and whenever a user is logged in, I must display all of the posts that have the user in the 1st field, this is what I found:

In **wp_user** the ID of the user I'll be using to test it will have: **user_id = 3**

In **wp_postmeta**, I have a row with these values:

**-post_id=92
-meta_value=3**

And in **wp_posts**, in the **ID = 92**, I have the specific post name I was looking for.

I'm pretty confused on how to make this code dynamically, so any user will be able to see their own posts. **And BTW, the post_author is the admin, so I can't use that field**

Basiclly, I must retrieve the post_id from wp_postmeta by only using the the meta_value which I've seen a couple of guides but can't really understand how to do it. I know I must use wp_get_current_user(). Please someone explain me with detail how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: correct me if I am wrong , you need to fetch the posts by a specific user through user id . ?

Comment: That's exactly what I must do, user id being wp_get_current_user()

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php you need to place this hook , this hook is fired whenever a post is added or updated you need to use this for saving post id in the post meta table.

```
  function enter_post_id( $post_id ) {

          wp_get_current_user()  // Get current user id with this 
          update_post_meta()($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique) 
          // add a meta key say 'user_id' and place the value of user_id as meta value


    }
    add_action( 'save_post', 'enter_post_id' );
```

Now You have the match completed , you just need to query through the post meta table and get the post id for the user , and then from wp_posts show only the post's with matched ID.

Hope this helps . Feel free to ask if you have any confusion.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still confused, to initialize the function I must have the post_id right? but i dont know what the post_id is if I don't search for it first with meta_value

Comment: This is an action hook whenever a post is created or updated it automatically executes the function and passes it the post_id , you do not have to pass it yourself.

Comment: How do I query through the postmeta to get the post id for the user? Sorry I'm just starting out with WP

Answer (score 0):

No problem :) Use this function.

```
function get_post_id(){ 
global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='user_id' AND meta_value= $user_id ", OBJECT ); 
// Where $user_id is the id you get from wp_current_user() 

}
```

Now var dump this $result to see the post_id

loop through this to get values for each post id